# pygame issue: sprite running over trees

Tags: python, class, events, pygame, sprite

I'm creating a game where you can explore a terrain, always random & computer generated. The player, which is a sprite, is supposed to only run on the grass blocks, and it shouldn't be able to run into trees. In other words, the player can only run on grass.

However, despite hours of debugging, the player still can run on trees, which is plenty annoying.

```
import pygame, player # the module where the Player class is defined
import block # the module where the Block class is  defined
...
#setting varibles, player, ...
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
create_world() # create the map of the world

while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, blocks, False)
    location = player.rect.centerx # defined to use as return spot in case of tree
    # player is player.Player instance, blocks is group of all the blocks
    # the block.Block class has an attribute called 'type'; grass = 'block'
    # tree = 'tree'
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed = [-30, 0] # the varible to update player's location
                if hit[0].type == tree: # if hit tree
                    player.rect.centerx = location
                ...
        if e.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            reset_speed() # speed = [0, 0], to prevent constant movement

    player.update(speed) # update the player
    reset_speed() # not really useful
    render_world() # blit the world & player
pygame.quit()
```

The `if hit[0].type == 'tree': ...` thing should've worked, but it didn't. Why?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your trees on grass ? :P so hit[0] == 'grass' and hit[1] == 'tree' ? :P

Comment: No. My trees are not on grass. The render_world() function chooses between trees & grass, so that won't be possible. But I will try it.

Comment: @JulienPalard: No use.

Comment: Julien's comment raises an issue though, spritecollide returns a list, and you are always taking the first element, you should check any other elements that may be returned, if not for this problem then maybe another in the future!

Answer (score 0):

So, to help yourself the standard handling in a loop is to move first, then handle collisions, this way you are privvy to both the previous position and the collided position.

As such in your current loop the player may be hitting a tree but is simply moving to the same position.

read through the loop step by step and try this out:

e.g.

```
 loop N:
  hit returns []
  location is set to (posN)
  speed is set
  player moves to (posN+1)
 loopN+1:
  hit returns [tree]
  location is set to (posN+1)
  speed is set
  player is reset to "location", but that is just (posN+1)
  player moves to (posN+2)
```

and so on and so on. From this hopefully you can see that it -is- working, just not as you expected, i could dig up the old phrase about computers always being right and whatnot

**Solution:**

Rewrite this slightly and consider handling movement first then checking collision second inside the loop, and this will become easier to understand.